# Solving a nonlinear recurrence equation

Tags: difference-equations

How to solve the following nonlinear recurrence equation using `RSolve`?

$$a(n+1):=\frac{1-(1-a(n)^4)^{1/4}}{1+(1-a(n)^4)^{1/4}} , \quad a(0):=\sqrt{2}-1$$

I tried:

```
RSolve[{a[n + 1] == (1 - (1 - a[n]^4)^(1/4))/(1 + (1 - a[n]^4)^(1/4)),
a[0] == Sqrt[2] - 1}, a[n], n]
```

but there is no answer.

Then I tried `Wolfram Alpha`, but $a(3)$ and $a(4)$ equal zero!

```
WolframAlpha["a[n + 1] =(1 - (1 - a[n]^4)^(1/4))/(1 + (1 - \
a[n]^4)^(1/4)), a(0)=Sqrt(2)-1", {{"Values", 1}, "Content"}]
```

[image]

Comment: What makes you think there should be a closed-form solution?

Answer (score 1):

Aquick and dirty answer

```
 a[0] := N[Sqrt[2] - 1]
 a[n_] := a[n] = (1 - (1 - a[n - 1]^4)^(1/4))/(1 + (1 - a[n - 1]^4)^(1/4))
```

The repetition of a[n] is for memorization.

Comment: This just implements the recurrence; the OP seems to want the explicit solution.

Comment: $a(n)=0$ for $n\geq3$, I tried `a[0] := N[Sqrt[2] - 1, 200]` but nothing change

Comment: In my computer with  N[Sqrt[2] - 1, 200],  a[1]= 0.00373489, a[2]=2.43231*10^-11,a[3]=0. Perhaps restart your kernel

Comment: I have tried to change the precision of the machine a[0] := SetPrecision[N[Sqrt[2] - 1, 200], 20],a[0] := SetPrecision[N[Sqrt[2] - 1, 200], 20] it change nothing for a[3] and a[4]

Comment: you can start with symbolic `a[0]` then `N[a[3],20]` yields `~10^-44`, `a[4] ~ 10^-175` is there a point to this?